# How to predict what the final result of a recipe will weigh?

Tags: substitutions, cheese, mascarpone

I have a recipe for a mascarpone substitute. How much does that recipe make? I need a pound's worth, so I don't know if that will be a enough or is too much.

Here is the recipe:

```
1 16 oz block of cream cheese,
1/2 cup sour cream,
1/4 cup heavy whipping cream,
```

Blend until smooth

Answer (score 6):

Your end result if you follow that recipe would weigh approximately 22 ounces, or 1 pound 6 ounces, or 1.375 pounds. (There are 16 ounces in a pound. Fluid ounce and ounce as a unit of weight are not exactly the same thing, but pretty darn close considering the ingredients you are working with; there are 8 fluid ounces in an American "cup", a "fluid ounce" of water weighs one ounce)

In the future if you have questions like this with other ingredients (particularly how much does a volumetric measurement [1 cup, or 1 Tablespoon] of an ingredient weigh), you might find this chart helpful: [Master Weight Chart](http://www.kingarthurflour.com/recipe/master-weight-chart.html)

Maybe this will help too: To make 1 pound of your recipe you would need 330g of Cream Cheese, 82g of Sour Cream and 41g of Whipping Cream.

Comment: +1 for figuring out what was being asked (and for providing a good answer).

Comment: It's worth noting that 82ml is almost exactly 1/3 of a metric cup, and 41ml is almost exactly 1/6 of a metric cup.  If that's any help.

Comment: In the US, a fluid ounce of water doesn't weigh an ounce. The US uses the Queen Anne fluid ounce, which is the volume of an ounce of wine, not water -- and wine is less dense than water. So a US fluid ounce of water weighs 1.04 ounces. In the UK, a fluid ounce of water _does_ weigh an ounce.

Comment: @MikeScott, Ok, whatever. An milliliter of heavy whipping cream doesn't weigh exactly a gram either. She's working with dairy products, not anthrax.